# Как поставить нужный порядок элементов в Bootstrap 5? (нестандартная ситуация)

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Моя проблема заключается в следующем:

1. При адаптивной верстке необходимо, чтобы при расширении экрана xxl+ было вот так:
   [image: 3 квадрата, красный, синий и зеленый. Красный и синий стоят в одном столбце. Зеленый занимает "две строки и по высоте как красный на синем.]
2. При остальном расширении (xl и меньше) необходимо создать следующий порядок:
   [image: порядок блоков вертикально сверху вниз: красный синий зеленый (при width: 100%)]

Answer (score 0):

Дока по тому что вы ищите
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#direction

Вам необходимо поиграть с данными свойствами изучить их работу и собрать то что требуется. Делайте группировку блоков и у же к ним применяйте реверс.
По ссылки, что выше, найдете много полезной информации как решить не только это, главное хорошо изучи как все работает на личном опыте

Пример решения 1

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

Пример решения 2

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column-reverse">
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```